# change Wordpress permalinks and redirect new urls 301

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess

I was using this WordPress permalink string.

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html
```

but now I want to change it to, and redirect all old URLs to new URLs

```
/?p=65
```

Sample old URL is:

```
http://www.example.com/dead-hahaha_bruhhh.html
```

The new URL will be:

```
http://www.example.com/?p=123
```

My `.htaccess` file is currently using default WordPress vars. How can I 301 redirect all my old URLs to new URLs?

I tried to use this, but it's not working.

Comment: The "WordPress permalink string" which you say you were using does not match the "sample old URL" you have given? "I tried to use this" - You tried to use _what_?

Answer (score 2):

Just choose `Plain` permalink settings on `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` page. Wordoress would auto redirect all posts.

Comment: It should be pointed out that when changing permalink structure, the redirect that happens is basically a guess using a `LIKE` query on the slug. There are cases where you will end up getting redirected to the wrong post.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below snippet that's for another question that i have already respond:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/417549/143910

Comment: I think that does the opposite of what this question is asking?